# Why is sourcing in .screenrc not supported?

Tags: source, gnu-screen

I would like to have the following code in my .screenrc

```
 source /Users/masi/bin/screen/file.screen
```

However, I observe that sourcing at .screenrc is not supported.

**Whi is sourcing in .screenrc not supported?**

Comment: @freiheit: Thank you for pointing out the mistake in the heading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested and "source /path/to/a/file" in my .screenrc worked perfectly.

Does the user have permissions to read that file?

What version of screen?  What OS?

Comment: Besides, it should be $PATH, otherwise it won't take the variable content.

Comment: My question was confusing. --- I clarified it.

Comment: @freiheit: I have permissions to use read the file. My Screen is 4.00.03. I use OS X.

Comment: I found the reason for the bug. Screen does not understand `~/bin/screen/file.screen`, but instead it understands `/Users/masi/bin/screen/file.screen`. --- Do you know how you can make Screen to understand `~`

Comment: try `$HOME/bin/screen/file.screen`